# Bootable dual-Win installation USB flash drive based on BCD

Tags: windows, boot, usb-flash-drive, bcd, bcdedit

I made a flash with Win 10 installation on top of NTFS/BCD system after which I've added other bootable images to BCD like TeraByte Image for Windows, EaseUS Partition Master etc, all WinPE loaded through BCD as selectable options, also Memtest86+ as iso, but this I've done with EasyBCD's own BCD->GRUB->iSO Linux I don't know what thingy (anyway).

So far all of them work fine, but I'm stuck at the next "phase".

I've noticed that Win 10 requires the source folder structure to be that of the DVD, i.e. source folder should be on the root of the flash drive, or during setup it will throw that driver requirement/loading window and won't continue past.

I've hit a snag as how to add Win 7's install wim on there as BCD's entry is pointing to boot.wim and I can't rename Win 7's, nor Win 10's, source folder as it would fall apart.

Anybody have any pointers or maybe a solution as how to add Win 7's wim in there?

NOTE: EasyBCD's iso loading doesn't help as it gives the same issue it does as if I rename the source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) can edit the complete boot configuration.

For example you move install.wim from \sources\ to \abc\def\ folder, then edit "Application Device" of corresponding wim boot entry from "N:\sources\install.wim" to "N:\abc\def\install.wim".

Note: "Application Device" + "Application Path" make up a whole thing = complete path to Windows loader! (be it also inside a .wim or whatever package format)

The same holds for "OS Device" + "System Root".